# change image.source when tapped

Tags: c#, image, windows-store-apps

I'm a novice programmer so don't be brutal.
I'm making a game for Windows Store, and I want to animate a run cycle. I made many GIF animations but all have BLACK background, and I need it transparent. So I've decided to make a run cycle using DispatcherTimer. Everything works fine, but the images don't change :/

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        numer++;
        if (numer > 8) numer = 1;
        hero.Source.Equals("Assets/Anim/" + nazwa + numer + ".png");

    }
```

Also, When I TAP a different image, it should change the image and other images, but it doesn't... what is wrong?

```
bool sun = true;

    private void Image_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sun = !sun;
        if (sun == false)
        {
            Image1.Source.Equals("moon.png");
            Image2.Source.Equals("ON.png");
        }
        else
        {
            Image1.Source.Equals("sun.png");
            Image2.Source.Equals("OFF.png");
        }
    }
```

The xaml works fine, as the images are shown.

I have checked this question:
[ImageTools on Windows Phone 8, changing ImageSource and DataContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14926779/imagetools-on-windows-phone-8-changing-imagesource-and-datacontext)

but I get loads of errors. I don't seem to understand how the property changed works.

Comment: Using `Image1.Source.Equals("moon.png");` does not do what you think it does. It compares whatever is in `Image1.Source` to `"moon.png"` and returns a boolean. You might want to try setting the property like this: `Image1.Source = new Uri("moon.png");` I don't have an IDE right now, so it might not be a `Uri`.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm using the URI way and I got the error:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code. Additional Information: System.Uri cannot be changed into Windows.Foundation.Uri class For more info check: go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems to be a small mistake. You are using the wrong method.

```
 Image.Source.Equals()
```

is a boolean method that simply compares the current source with the "source" you give as arguement and will return true or false based on the comparison.
But what you want is to set the source of the image.
So you need to use:

```
 Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("moon.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

This will set the source of the Image to the new image you want.

Comment: I get an error:
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code.

Additional Information:  System.Uri cannot be changed into  Windows.Foundation.Uri class

For more info check: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849.

Comment: Stupid me - reread the given link a GAZYLION times until it struck my stupid head :) 
I need to use and the new Uri("ms-appx:///source.png", UriKind.Absolute) and it ALL works. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "moon.png" is in the main folder in your solution, the two solutions both work:

```
BitmapImage tn = new BitmapImage();
tn.SetSource(Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(@"moon.png", UriKind.Relative)).Stream);
Image1.Source = tn;
```

Or

```
Image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("moon.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Windows RT needs URI to be Absolute - I wrote that in a comment above your answer. It works for me :)